# Creating a backup plan for TFS 2010 fails everytime

Tags: tfs

Here is the screenshot of the error I get

[image]

The following steps I have taken which still are not able to resolve the issue.

- In the Acount section of the backup plan I have tried with both
  Network Service and also My domain account
- On the shared path I have given my domain user account full access to
  the shared path.
- I also went ahead and gave Everyone Full privileges on the same path
  [Just to test]
- I have given the same domain account permission to SQL Server backup
  using sp_addrolemember 'db_backupoperator', 'MyDOMAIN\my.accountName'
- I went to the Build controller pc and in Start->Run entered the
  address of the shared path and tried to manually create a folder and
  a text file and I was able to create the folder and edit the text
  file.
- I changed the share path to another pc on the network and repeated
  the same steps as above with the same results

On opening the log file I am seeing the following

[snippet]

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup.SqlBackup(Server srv)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.Admin.Helpers.BackupFactory.TestBackupCreation(String path)
[Error  @08:43:52.062] !Verify Error!: Account 'MyDOMAIN\my.accountName' failed to create backups **using path \XXXXX\DailyBackups**
[Info   @08:43:52.062] "Verify: Grant Backup Plan Permissions\Root\VerifyDummyBackupCreation(VerifyTestBackupCreatedSuccessfully): Exiting Verification with state Completed and result Error"
[Info   @08:43:52.062] !Verify Result!: 4 Completed, 0 Skipped: 3 Success, 1 Errors, 0 Warnings

[end-snippet]

The path is not the same path that I had entered. **It is still pointing to the older path** I had entered before I changed the UNC to a different pc. The path reported in the log file is different from the path in the screen shot above. What is going on?

Please help me create a backup plan for TFS 2010. Thanking you for your time...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms and found the fix.

I was using a Domain Admin account which had all the necessary permissions. My SQL instance account also has all the required permissions but TFS Backup Wizard kept saying I did not have the necessary permissions.

**!Verify Error!: Account XXXXXX failed to create backups using path \XXX\TFS Backups\NightlyPlan**

The wizards log wasn't very helpful either, so I dug around and found the error in the general logs:

[Error  @11:49:18.206] Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Backup failed for Server 'TFS-01'.  ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open backup device **'\XXX\TFS\temp_20130422124916.bak'**. Operating system error 67(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

So you can see that the error was because I had a space in the Share Name:
"TFS Backups"
This got truncated to just "TFS".

I changed the Share to "TFSBackups" and it all started to work.

LOL @MS engineers - I still instinctively leave out spaces in folder names (remember short filenames) but I had thought that by now this was just an old superstition that I could drop. Silly me.

Adam

Answer (score 1):

If you are making changes in the backup plan and it is giving you an error, perform these simple steps.

1. Go to 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Server Configuration'
2. Open ConfigPT.xml file in editor or notepad.
3. Change your backup destination in `<BackupPath>\\192.168.0.1\TFS001\daily\</BackupPath>`.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

The account you are logged in as when you run the wizard needs proper permissions to read/write from the backup share *and* grant permissions to other accounts to do the same.

Comment: how do you give proper permissions to a user account, specifically for the purpose: read/write from the backup share and to grant permissions to other accounts to do the same?